# Multiple routers - intermitantly can access internet, but not other networked devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

Help - I have what is probably a very simple problem, but its stumped me, and is really winding up the family! Any solutions, or things I could check are much appreciated.

**My setup**

I have basic home network with two routers cabled together (I'll call A and B), each broadcasting Wifi using the same SSID, WPA2 and Channels 3 on A and 8 on B. I have multiple laptops/tablets etc connecting to the network, together with a NAS. Routers A, B and the NAS all have static IP addresses within the same subnet.

Router A has DHCP enabled and assigned IPs not statically set for the routers/NAS. Router B has DHCP disabled.

Router A - BT HomeHub 4 (Type B), Router B - Technicolor TG582n

**The problem**

Every so often, I boot up a laptop and I am unable to communicate with the NAS, Router B or any other device on the network (either via HTTP, Pings, both with hostname and IP address), however I can ping/connect via HTTP to Router A (default gateway) and to the internet. If I use another laptop at the same time, I am able to access everything as normal (so don't think its a problem with the NAS etc).

The problem occurs intermittently (ie. one day it works, the next it doesn't), and it occurs on multiple different devices, so I don't think is setup problem with the laptops.

**What seems to temporarily fix it**

- Rebooting Router A seems to generally fix the problem.

**Things I've tried to permanently fix it**

- Swapping A & B, and 3rd router C - Using different combinations of the physical devices, but set up as above.
- Assigning the affected machine a static IP address (from the client, or reserving an address in DHCP)